# How many UAT environment are sufficient

Tags: unit-testing, testing, business-logic, user-acceptance-testing, uat

Our client has asked on some data points as to how many UAT(User acceptance) environments would suffice our need. We have 6 tracks(set of users) with UAT happening in a diff. timing windows for each track. I want to gather some data points How many UAT environment should We setup ? Is it based on users, industry standards. etc. please give some useful links

Answer (score 1):

You have to measure the test coverage (automatic or manual) in order to understand if your test effective enough. It is worth to calculate how the coverage increase by the additional UAT track. For example lets assume that your UAT test should provide 75% coverage. Then you need to measure what coverage provides one track. In case if the additional track will significant improve the coverage you have to continue add the tracks until you will reach the expected 75%.
Please see the following [link](http://www.getzephyr.com/sites/default/files/content/resources/The%20Science%20of%20Running%20Effective%20UAT%20Cycles.pdf) for more info

Comment: You have several good code working examples here. When you clone it you will see sauce lab code included.